# How to replace a file in .msi file using msitools (or anything that runs) on macOS

Tags: msitools

I have a Java application with embedded JDK. I support this on Windows,Linux and macOS and I develop (and do everything I can) on macOS.

I use my own Ant script to build and package the app.

My problem is that to release for example Linux executable I need to build the code on Linux.

And similarly for Windows.

After inspecting this it looks like I could do a typical release for Linux on macOS with some effort and build a deb package without involving Linux.

Now I would like to do the same with Windows. I have an .msi installer for my app and to release of new version of my app all I need to do is to replace the app.jar inside the .msi.

It looks like msitools might be the answer but I cannot figure out how.